# Vuetify: How to execute a method when a dialog is closed?

Tags: vuetify.js

I want to do something like this:

```
<v-dialog @close="close">
...
</v-dialog>
```

How to execute a method when a dialog is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add v-model to your dialog:

```
<v-dialog v-model="showDialog">
...
</v-dialog>
```

and then add a watch on the model data:

```
data() {
  return {
    showDialog: false
  }
},
watch: {
  showDialog(newvalue, oldvalue) {
    if (!newvalue && oldvalue)
       // code to be exceuted when dialog model become false
  }
}
```

Otherwise, if you want a persistent dialog, you can add a method to the card action into the dialog:

```
  <v-dialog v-model="show">
    <v-card>
     <v-card-actions>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn
        color="green darken-1"
        text
        @click="methodOnClose"
      >
        Disagree
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn
        color="green darken-1"
        text
        @click="dialog = false"
      >
        Agree
      </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</v-dialog>
```

and methodOnClose is

```
methods: {
  methodOnClose() {
    // your method when dialog has been closed
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for how to implement [event handling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) on the dialog. This isn't Vuetify specific and is handled by the Vue framework. As the docs show, you need to provide a method in your component and use its name as the value of the `@close` event handler attribute. So, something like:

```
..
methods: {
    close: function (event) {
      // Do closey things
    }
  }
```